# How can I convert JSON to a bitmap image using C?

Tags: arrays, c, json

I'm receiving JSON from a REST API that contains the bitmap data for an image. How can I convert that JSON into a bitmap image using C? Are there any libraries or tools that you would recommend for a task like this

Comment: **How** is the bitmap data encoded in the JSON file? Base64? Base64Url? Base16? A `data:` URI? As a URI to a hosted resource? A JSON array of `Byte` values? And what Bitmap format is it using? e.g. Windows DIB? PNG? WBMP?

Comment: Would you mind to read "[ask]" (again)? Recommendations are out of scope here. You might come back later and [edit] your question, providing a [example], complete with a simple input and expected output. And tell us where you stumble.